# Styled Components v3 has empty theme object

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

After upgrading to styled-components@latest (3.1.0) upon starting the app, this error is thrown:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'margin' of undefined`

Upon inspection, it looks like the theme object is empty in a component defined like this:

`` export const Form = styled.form`
  ${({ theme }) => theme.layout.margin.all.small};
`; ``

Logging `theme` here returns `{}`, however at the `<ThemeProvider>` level in jsx, the theme logs as expected, complete with all the values.

If I downgrade to 2.4.0, it works fine and as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there were multiple versions of styled-components colliding with each other.

Remove the duplicates and worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This could have multiple causes but I do not think it has anything to do with v3 as the theme API hasn’t changed.

Have you maybe introduced a circular dependency while upgrading?